# SOAP requests to some WCF methods doesn't work

Tags: c#, php, wcf, soap, action

PHP-client takes WSDL of my WCF service. Thare are two methods (for example) - GetEntityTypeList() and GetPermissions(...). PHP-client send two SOAP requests.

For GetEntityTypeList():

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.mywork.com/BusinessEntity" xmlns:ns2="http://www.mywork.com">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ApplicationServer>
      <SessionId>25872680517</SessionId>
    </ApplicationServer>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:GetEntityTypeList/>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

For GetPermissions(...):

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.mywork.com/BusinessEntity" xmlns:ns2="http://www.mywork.com">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ApplicationServer>
      <SessionId>25872680517</SessionId>
    </ApplicationServer>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:GetPermissions>
      <ns1:type>1</ns1:type>
      <ns1:id>1</ns1:id>
    </ns1:GetPermissions>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Then WCF-server catch first request like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.mywork.com/BusinessEntity" xmlns:ns2="http://www.mywork.com">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ApplicationServer xmlns="http://www.mywork.com/">
      <SessionId>25872680517</SessionId>
    </ApplicationServer>
    <To SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://10.128.240.23:55564/BusinessEntityServer/IEntityType</To>
    <Action SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://www.mywork.com/BusinessEntity/IEntityType/GetEntityTypeList</Action>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:GetEntityTypeList />
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

As you can see there are two additional blocks - **To** and **Action**. And the first request works fine.
But the second request does not reach the server. And PHP-client catch the exception:

*The message with Action 'http://www.mywork.com/BusinessEntity/IPermissionEx/GetPermissions' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver. Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).*

Why?

I will show WSDL If necessary.

Comment: What binding are you using on your WCF service?

Comment: Is the client using the same binding while calling those two operations?

Comment: I am using BasicHttpBinding. PHP is using SOAP 1.1.

Comment: I do not know what did the PHP developer, but now every methods work fine.

Comment: I think it depended on PHP-side caching.